Using BlackBerry Dynamics SDK with SwiftData for Secured Storage
I'm currently working on a project where I need to implement secured storage for data using BlackBerry Dynamics SDK in Swift.
I've found documentation and examples for using secured storage with CoreData, but I couldn't find any resources for implementing it with SwiftData.
Does anyone have experience or knowledge on how to integrate BlackBerry Dynamics SDK's secured storage feature with SwiftData? Any guidance, examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated.

SwiftData (added in iOS 17) isn't currently supported for storage in the BlackBerry Dynamics secure container. For now, you'll need to continue to use CoreData in your application.
